# Can I transform compiled classes using Byte Buddy during compilation?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, byte-buddy

I need to modify some class in Flutter framework during compilation of my Flutter application.
Thought, it's a good idea to use the byte-buddy-gradle-plugin for this purpose.
Added this into my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "net.bytebuddy.byte-buddy-gradle-plugin"
byteBuddy {
    transformation {
        plugin = "com.example.BuildPlugin"
        // classPath = ...
    }
}
```

BuildPlugin is executed succesfully on compileDebugKotlin task, but it processes only my project classes.
Is there any possibility to point it to flutter.jar somehow, maybe using classPath transformation parameter?
I tried to use this part from plugin README:

```
configurations {
  examplePlugin "foo:bar:1.0"
}
```

with some modifications, but got "Gradle DSL method not found: 'examplePlugin()'" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not really compatible to how build pipelines work. What you can do is that you use the shade plugin to copy a dependency's code into your project and then process it from there. Otherwise, Java agents would be the solution for this but Android does not support it.

Comment: Right, I tried to use Byte Buddy in runtime, and came to the same conclusion. Will try to use Flutter from source, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Android Transform API and Javassist.
Please check [my GitHub](https://github.com/Skyggedans/gradle-patchflutteraccessibility-plugin) if anyone is interested how.